# Ошибка: resource references are not supported at this language level

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Пытаюсь скопилировать и запустить проект, но выдает ошибку: resource references are not supported at this language level.

В настройках у меня все выставлено так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я уже все настройки какие только можно менял, идею перезапускал, но ошибка не пропадает.

Comment: а драйвер posgres к проекту прицеплен ?

Comment: попробуй удалить iml файл и открой проект

Comment: вы потеряли скобку `)`

Comment: Драйвер работает, так как если просто в try вкинуть код, то sql команды проходят.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Конструкция *try-with-resources* работает с ресурсами, которые реализуют интерфейс `AutoCloseable`. Об этом говорится в [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). Метод `Class.forName` возвращает объект типа `Class`, который не реализует данный интерфейс.

Соответственно, использовать `Class.forName` в *try-with-resources* нельзя.

Более того, есть ещё одна проблема (хотя первой вполне достаточно для создания некомпилируемого кода): нельзя просто написать, например,

```
try (new FileReader("file.txt"))
```

Должно быть присваивание:

```
try (FileReader reader = new FileReader("file.txt"))
```

Код `Class.forName` должен быть внутри блока `try`:

```
try
{
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
}
catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```